# Yii: render the login.php view into another view's Div tag

Tags: view, yii, render

so im working on a page to learn Yii. this is it: http://devcave.freeiz.com/

What i am trying to do is, when i click on login, a div is sliding down, where the login.php form should be.
The question is how do i render that into the main.php's div tag.

i tryed `$this->renderPartial('//site/login',array('model'=>$model));` , but i get Undefined variable: model error.
I read trough the Understanding yii view rendering flow but it seems i didnt quit get the point.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:

```
$this->renderPartial('site/login',array('model'=>new LoginForm));
```

And in *login view* you should define `action` like this:

```
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    // ...
    'action' => $this->createUrl( 'site/login' ),
    // ...
```

Comment: its working. I need to format my login.php form now to fit in that box, cuase it looks like this now: http://devcave.freeiz.com Could you explain why it works now. Is it cause of the action thing? Cause i already did the array('model'=>new LoginForm).

Comment: @Toma - You were using $model before as a variable that hadn't been defined.  Boris' code works because he explicitly ensured that the 'model' passed to the view via renderPartial() was defined . . .

Comment: i know dont get me wrong, befor Boris posted the answer i tryed that 'model'=>new LoginForm, but whitout the action=>.... so probably there is the sullotion to the problem.

Comment: Let say you are using `renderPartial` part only, but in the _view_ `action` wasn't set. And this `renderPartial` is called from _site/index_ view. In this case form's action at the _login_ view, will point to _site/index_, in which action you don't have validation or any kind of processing of the `LoginForm`. That's why setting _action_ to _site/login_ works. Because form will submit user's data to the _site/login_ action, where is the validation and so on for the `LoginForm`.

e.g. if you don't define _action_ for your `CActiveForm` Yii will set current controller's action.

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you didn't defined a variable named $model in your controller and this variable is needed in the View login.

In your controller when you call

```
$this->render('yourView', array());
```

you'll have to add in the second array the datas that you want to pass to the Login view

```
$this->render('yourView', array('model'=>$model));
```

Don't hesitate to post your code if you need a more specific answer!

Comment: uhh well there is not much to post, cause i dont really know what i have to do. In my controller i know there is a $model = new LoginForm. That is creating the model. So normally when i go on the login button, in the main content area the login for loaded. But i want it to be loaded in the main.php's div as u can see in the link i posted.